# How can I copy & paste entire rows with distinct values to a new sheet on varying cell ranges?

Tags: vba, excel

I know there's many StackOverlow Q&A's on copying & pasting from a cell value in VBA. However, I can't seem to make it work for my own project. I want to copy the entire row(s) if it matches the Distinct Store# (non incremental) in Column H into a new sheet (in this code below, "Sheet1") which already has a template layout where I copy/paste the values. The template looks the same on every sheet before any data is filled in, except the first 2 tabs which have the data ("Appointments" and "Invoices").

I came up with the VBA below, but here's the catch- the cell# that it pastes the row(s) (in the code below, "A10") changes based on the Store #. This is because I am copying rows from the 1st sheet ("Appointments") in the workbook from the distinct Store#, then deleting the empty rows above the area where the 2nd sheet ("Invoices") data goes. Some stores may return 10 rows or none at all. The Case, which is the Store #, is currently manually put in one by one. Should it be an array instead?

Anyway...I was hoping to automate the copying/pasting and loop for each store to their sheet. Maybe I'm going about this wrong, but would anyone be kind enough to suggest how to solve my error code **"Method or data member not found."** as well as provide any suggestions on making my code better for a loop for filtered cell copying to different spots for each sheet.

Simple explanation of my step by step process:

1.Filter Store # from "Appointments" sheet.

2. Copy all rows for that store and paste into a new sheet with template named "Sheet1" in B3. 
3. Filter Store # from "Invoices" sheet. 
4. Copy all rows for that store and paste into the previously made sheet named "Sheet" under the above rows. (Some stores do not have invoices, so this section is blank/NULL). Paste destination cell for "Invoices" will be different for each store# depending on how many rows they get from the "Appointments" sheet (could be A10 or A25). 
5. LOOP- Next store #, next sheet (sheet2).

```
    Sub CopyToNewSheetInv()

    Dim i As Range
    Dim book As Workbooks
    Dim sheet1 As Worksheets
    Dim sheet2 As Worksheets

    Set book = Workbooks("SampleWorkbookName")
    Set sheet1 = Worksheets("AllInvoices")
    Set sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For Each i In sheet1.Range("H:H")

    Select Case i.Value

        Case 1243

            sheet2.Range("A10").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value = i.EntireRow.Value

        Case Else

    End Select

    Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: do you really want to paste the **entire row** from one sheet to the next, or just the columns with data for that row? I would think the latter is what you want, in which case setting the exact columns will help speed up your code.

Comment: Say it's Store #100. There are 30 appointments and 2 invoices. I want all Appointment and Invoice data (first 2 tabs) for Store #100. Store #125 may have 14 appointments and 10 invoices. What I didn't include in this question is that eventually, I am using a matching formula for the appointments and invoices on "Sheet1". The question above is just asking how to get the data onto "Sheet1" SO I can match with my other formulas/scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub CopyToNewSheetInv()

Dim i As Range
Dim book As Workbook
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim sheet2 As Worksheet

Set book = Workbooks("SampleWorkbookName.xlsx")
Set sheet1 = book.Worksheets("AllInvoices")
Set sheet2 = book.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'iterate only thorugh those cells in H that have data, not all 1.04 million
For Each i In sheet1.Range("H1", sheet1.Range("H" & sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Select Case i.Value
        Case 1243,"1243"
            sheet2.Rows(sheet2.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = sheet1.Rows(i.Row).Value
        Case Else
    End Select
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting the H:H error. That should speed it up greatly.  Same error message. Highlights the "Rows" in the following line: For Each i In sheet1.Range("H1", sheet1.Range("H" & sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))   ****I need to edit my original message because I realized I can use the same cell to paste. Delete the blank spaces above the "Invoices" data AFTER I paste. Ugh...Should have thought about this earlier!

Comment: Thanks Scott H.  But now it's a Sub or Function Not Defined error. What did I set wrong?

Comment: @MMBInTraining on which line do you get the new error?

Comment: Set book = Workbooks("SampleWorkbookName") - Error:9 Subscript out of range  (Looks like it is referring to the A10000 range)

Comment: @MMBInTraining no, if the error is on that line then you have typed the name wrong.  and Do a Scott said make sure you have the extension

Comment: @MMBInTraining I have tested this now and it works for me.  So I realize your code above is not for the actual situation.  Make sure that the data in H is a true number and not a string. If it is a string then see the edit I just made.  Another thing to do is create a stop in the code then hit F8 to go line by line through it and see what it is doing wrong on each line.

Comment: Say I have 40 rows of data on the sheet "All Invoices". The rows with the selected store is pasting on the correct sheet, but at row 41 because of this following line I think:  sheet2.Rows(Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = sheet1.Rows(i.Row).Value

Comment: @MMBInTraining I missed a sheet reference in that line.  see edit, it should work now.

Comment: Thanks guys! You've been a great help. I appreciate it. Marked your answer.